# Need ASP.NET 4.8 (.NET Framework) application to be part of Google K8s

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an .NET Framework based WebAPI application which is depending on some .NET based components (not support .NET core) and use to deploy on IIS on-premises which works well. Now, we want to leverage the kubernetes (a.k.a k8s) on Google cloud.

But, due to too much dependency on windows OS, is that possible for me to continue using the same application without converting to .NET 5 (which is something impossible due to dependency on some windows based tools) and host on windows based docker container and host on GKE pods?

If yes, do I need to have any windows license?

Can anyone help me in suggesting the best approach for this, if windows based container works with GKE k8s, how can I do these all together. From creating windows based docker image with my existing API application and hosting on GKE k8s.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/deploy-dotnet-applications#containers this could help you

Comment: You can find .NET Framework container images documented at https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework/

Comment: Do you really want to use GKE here?  GKE does support windows containers, but you might want to consider simply starting with a Windows VM on Google Cloud or consider moving your app to .NET core and then using Linux containers on GKE.